# Play Framework - Json.format case class conversion with a case class

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I'm not able to get the following to work, so don't know if it's even possible:

```
case class ItemA(name:String,itemB:ItemB)
case class ItemB(name:String)

object ToJson{
   implicit val itemAJson = Json.format[ItemA]
   implicit val itemBJson = Json.format[ItemB]
}
```

I get a compile error of something like:

> No implicit format for ItemB available.
>   [error]   implicit val itemAJson = Json.format[ItemA]

Pretty sure it can't be done, but is there a sensible approach to take?

Play Framework 2.3

Comment: As your ItemA depends on ItemB so in order to create json.Format[ItemA] there must be defined json.Forma[ItemB] first,  hence change the order first define itemBJson then itemAJson

Comment: This fixed it. Want to add it as an answer and I can confirm that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your ItemA depends on ItemB so in order to create json.Format[ItemA] there must be defined json.Forma[ItemB] first, hence change the order first define itemBJson then itemAJson

```
implicit val itemBJson = Json.format[ItemB]
implicit val itemAJson = Json.format[ItemA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to **lazy** the implicit variables ... in this way it does not affect the order you write it. I have many jsonFormat and they all work correctly like this:

```
object ToJson {
   implicit lazy val itemAJson = Json.format[ItemA]
   implicit lazy val itemBJson = Json.format[ItemB]
}
```

Similar is the solution in the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Recursive-Types). for recursive types.